# Virtual COM Port with Nucleo F103RB on Windows 11

Tags: usb, stm32, stm32cubeide, nucleo, com-port

I followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@pasindusandima/stm32-usb-virtual-com-port-vcp-bc7cb1bd5f5 to set up a USB data transmission from my board to a Virtual COM Port.

After building the project and running with debugger, I only see "STMicroelectronics STLink Virtual COM Port (COM5)" and "ST-Link Debug" on my device manager. After using PuTTY to listen to serial port COM5, I see no activity in the terminal.

However, I noticed that the tutorial does not use COM5 and instead uses "STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port (COM10)". But when I run my program, no new USB devices show up, and only the original two mentioned before are present. How can I get the correct COM port to show up on my device manager?

USB Peripherals in STM32CubeIDE

- Connectivity > USB > Device (FS) with default settings
- Middleware & Software Packs > USB_DEVICE > Communication Device Class (Virtual Port Com) with default settings

Comment: What's your end goal?  How did you connect the USB cable to the STM32F103RB?  Note that the USB port on the Nucleo F103RB does NOT connect directly to the chip you are programming, instead it connects to the ST-Link.

Comment: The exact COM port number doesn't matter at all, it is assigned by Windows to a newly connected serial device (like disks C:\, D:\, E:\ and so on). Can you get an LED blinking?